# Bootstrap Template Migration issue within Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2013

I have a similar question to this one [CSS Not Linking](http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html)
[1](http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html): [CSS not linking to my index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797082/css-not-linking-to-my-index-html).

I am able to run the HTMLPage1 locally that was part of a Bootstrap Template.  It runs fine when it's not included into the Visual Studio 2013 Project.

The Bootstrap Template utilizes this format:

```
    <!-- Web Fonts -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;subset=cyrillic,latin'>

<!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

<!-- CSS Header and Footer -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/headers/header-default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/footers/footer-v1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme-colors/dark-blue.css"> 

<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/css/layerslider.css">

<!-- CSS Customization -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
```

However, from within Visual Studio, the CSS isn't linking, and I'm not sure if the problem has to do with the .NET 4.5 Bundling that I did, for the project which included all of the CSS.  I provided all of the scripts and css for bundling prior to adding HTMLPage1 to the project. This HTMLPage1 does not reference the BundleConfig.cs or the Bundle.Config.  All of the CSS links and script references are included within the HTMLPage1.

I have attempted with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style.css" type="text/css">
```

I have also tried this format which was the ASP.NET protocol for VS 2010:

```
 <link rel="Stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.css" type="text/css">
```

There are several other CSS links that are part of HTMLPage1, and it appears that none of them are getting referenced.

Here is the [HTMLPage1 Link](http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html)

Here is a screenshot of the DAV3 File Structure.  This includes the default ASP.NET 4.5 Forms Default.aspx.  I added HTMLPage1.html, the Scripts within Scripts, the CSS within Content Folder:
[image]

Hopefully this question isn't too simple, and somebody could give me some insight into the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your file structure as well? When I clicked on the link "HTMLPage1 Link" and viewed it's source, Boorstrap.min.css and style.css both are linked perfectly. So I am bit confused with the actual problem.

Comment: Well, the `html` file you linked has the css linked fine. The tilde `~` is only understood by ASP.net for files it handles - `.html` isn't one of them (unless you tinker with settings for ASP.net to handle "static" `.html`)....

Comment: @KiranVarsani are you referring to the file structure of the original template from where I copied this from?  I pretty much copied the CSS and images and put them into different folders within the .NET project.

Comment: I want to check where exactly your css files are in your folder structure? How are you attempting to run your site? If you are running your site from localhost and your html page is not on the root folder then your referencing will not work.

Comment: @KiranVarsani pls let me know if this screenshot works for you

Comment: Please double check where your css files are. Are they directly under Content folder or they are in a subfolder of the contect folder. The screenshot does not say that.

Comment: @KiranVarsani they are directly within Content Folder, as I mentioned they were also previously bundled with Bundle.Config, but I'm not referencing that bundle from this html page.

Comment: Please browse your index.html or HtmlPage1.html wherever your css files are not working, and post the url here. Just trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @KiranVarsani Im not sure what you mean by "browse" where the css isn't working...

Comment: You do not need css to be working to browse a site. All I am after is a url. e.g. http://localhost/something/something/anotherfolder/index.html

Comment: @KiranVarsani  is this what you are referring to?  http://localhost:57365/HtmlPage1.html   the same here:  http://www.petcenters.com/HtmlPage1.html

Comment: I cannot find any CSS problem on your page other than this one. assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/skins/fullwidth/skin.css. Please try refreshing your cache by pressing ctrl+F5 to reload your css. I have checked your code in detail, boorstrap works perfactly fine and your page is responsive to mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of migration issues:

There was 1 missing CSS: assets/plugins/layer-slider/layerslider/skins/fullwidth/skin.css.

There were 4 missing Font Files, and these were not apparent within the Bootstrap Template.

The App Initialization App.Init() needs to happen right after App.js.  This App.Init() was put after the layerslider, for which it caused a problem.

bootstrap.min.css 3.0.0 and that older version didn't work with this template, so I had to upgrade to bootstrap.min.css 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this. All I am doing is adding a forward slash right before Content in href. This will **NOT** work if your local url is something like http://localhost/SiteName/Default.aspx i.e. IIS hosted as a virtual application

But This will surely work when your url is something like, 
http://localhost:portnumber/Default.aspx or http://SiteName/Default.aspx

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/style.css" type="text/css">
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: that didn't help sorry